# Error while run mxmlc

Tags: apache-flex, air, mxml

I installed java 1.7 in my machine, 
Now I'm getting following  error while compiling mxmlc command for adobe air application..
**This application has failled to start bcoz MSVCR100.dill was not found.**

Please advice me...

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, here are my steps:
1. Install newest JRE (JRE7 currently) with default install dir(C:\Program Files\Java)
2. Copy C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll into system32 directory